# C# regex optional group not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get parts from these strings:
first:
2F4449534301224E4F204445534352495054494F4E20415641494C41424C45011F30303034342D30313230382D
second:
2F4449534301224E4F204445534352495054494F4E20415641494C41424C45011F30303130312D3032323534012630303130312D31303932342D

basically I want to return for both strings:
first:
2F(.+)011F(.+)2D
second:
2F(.+)011F(.+)0126(.+)2D

I am trying to use this pattern:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(this.__line, 
                      @"^2F.*22(.*)011F(.*)(0126.*)?.{2}$", 
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, when I try:

```
if (m.Success)
{
    if (m.Groups[3].Value != "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("good");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("bad");
}
```

I get "bad" from the second string because it is not matching the pattern. Am I not using the correct pattern?

Comment: Did you forget to capitalize the `f` in the second pattern or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern is greedy. You should use this patten instead:

```
^2F.*22(.*?)011F(.*?)(0126.*?)?.{2}$
```

The second group in your regex matches everything until the last 2 charcaters at the end because it is greedy and the last group is optional.

To make your matches nongreedy use a ? after the quantifier.

[Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/greedy.html) is more info about greedy and nongreedy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the "^".

2F.*22(.*)011F(.*)(0126.*)?.{2}$

http://regexpal.com/ is my hands down favorite regex tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you some advices. **These are not answers to your question**, just some good practices **tips**:

- The *anything but new line* (**.**) symbol has a very poor performance, you should avoid using it whenever possible. As I can see, you could replace it with **\S**
- For case insensitive match, use the syntax `(?i:pattern)`. This gives you the option of choosing **RegexOptions.Compiled**, which will give you a better performance
- For retrieving text, the use of named capture groups is recommended. Use the syntax `(?<name>pattern)`. This way you can retrieve it by `regexMatch.Groups["name"].Captures[0].Value`
- Whenever you have a group that you do not want to retrive (only for matching purposes), mark it as a non-capturing group, using the syntax `(?:pattern)`
- Lastly, [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is a great (yet paid) tool. Highly recommended.

Regards.